# Wordpress: Fetching Data from Database $wpdb of Specific User

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Hello I am working a project today. I want to print in front end the data of a specific user every time they login. When they login will get their user id and will fetch data from that specific user only.

[I have this database. I want vendor_id 3 when this vendor login will display only values of specific vendor if no values will return "No Commission Data for this user"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohDlZ.png)

Right now heres my wordpress wpdb code

```
<table border="1">
        <tr>
        <th>Vendor ID</th>
        <th>Total Due</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        global $wpdb;
        $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM wp_pv_commission" );
        $vendor = get_current_user_id();
        foreach ( $result as $userdata) {
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $userdata->vendor_id;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $userdata->total_due;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $userdata->time;?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </table>
```

[And it returns the data of this. But what I want is only as per user like right now Im login as vendor id 3. It show all. What is the proper wordpress php conditioning code I need to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dQX8.png)

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: you should add the code here as a code block and not as an image.

Comment: Sorry I added the code above im just new in stack not really using it before...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right but your condition is wrong for selecting the data from database

when you don't apply where clause, MYSQL will always return all the records. so for that you need to provide where clause in your query

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Vendor ID</th>
        <th>Total Due</th>
        <th>Time</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $vendor = get_current_user_id();
    $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM wp_pv_commission where vendor_id=".$vendor );
    foreach ( $result as $userdata) {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $userdata->vendor_id;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $userdata->total_due;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $userdata->time;?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

[How to use where clause in MySQL](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-where/)